# What is special in /Applications/ folder?

Tags: macos, applications, xcode, folders, preferences

What happens when an .app bundle going copy to the `/Applications/` folder? Are there any **processes** starting, any preferences copied to `/Library/` ? Is a copy to `/Applications/` folder a **special trigger/event** for the OS X?

I found that if I just copy Xcode then `com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist` appears in user's `Preferences` folder.

Answer (score 3):

With the exception of installing app with package manager, there is no special events if you only copy application to any folders. The preferences stored in Library or Application Support are created when you run the application for the first time.